# Return specific number of <td> with array data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck on this react table problem. I need to create a table with 3 `<td>` cells and within the `<td>` cells I need to insert some data that is coming from an array. The array length isn't known, it can be between, 0 to 3 elements. If there is data it needs to go into the correct `<td>` cell and if there isn't any data then the `<td>` needs to print out empty. None of my attempts return the correct number of `<td>` cells with/without data.

**Example of dataArray - Unknow number of arrays**

`const dataArray = []`

Or

`const dataArray = [1, 2, 3]`

```
let i;
const myTD = [];

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      if (dataArray.length() > 0) {
        dataArray.map((data, index) => {
          if (index === i + 1) {
            myTD.push(
              <td
                key={data._id}
              >
                {data}
              </td>
            );
          } else {
            dataArray.push(
              <td
                key={cryptoRandomString({ length: 10 })}
              >
                No data
              </td>
            );
          }
        });
      } else {
        dataArray.push(
          <td
            key={cryptoRandomString({ length: 10 })}
          >
            No array
          </td>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can utilize the array map method. You need to map the data from your array into the jsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you,

```
let i;
const myTD = [];

if (dataArray.length > 0) {
  dataArray.map((data, index) => {
      myTD.push(<td key={data._id}>{data}</td>);
  });
}

for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  if(!myTD[i]){
    myTD[i] = <td key={cryptoRandomString({ length: 10 })}>No data</td>
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/puqerudipi/edit?html,js,console) tested with simple data.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the array will always be 3 you can manually create the rows, then you can check if that information exists in the array and display that information or some other data by default.

```
const tds = Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, key) => (
    <td
      key={dataArray[key].id || cryptoRandomString({ length: 10 })}
    >
      // Check if field data exist or display a message
      {dataArray[key].data || 'No Data'}
    </td>
  ));
```

This will display:

```
[null, { data: 1, id: 1 }] as ['No Data', 1, 'No Data']
```

Comment: Please give an explanation about how this would solve the issue